# Generating lazy loaders in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, lazy-evaluation

I need to instantiate a lot of fields in a "lazy" way. Is there any plugin for Android Studio that could generate getters with lazy instantiation and make my life easier? 
I need my getter to look like this:

```
public String getName() {
    if(mName == null){
        mName = "Some value here"
    }
return mName;
}
```

Comment: Android Studio no such plugin available which make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the class you want to implement the getters and setters, hit ctrl + insert and a dialog will appear, click "Getter" or "Setter" and choose the variables you want to implement getters/setters for.

This also works for Override and Implement methods from classes you extend.

Hope this helps, happy coding.

Comment: This would generate just a regular getter. I've updated my question with an example.

Comment: I see. Looks like this issue has been submitted a couple of times but the feature has not been added yet. I tried looking for a plug-in but to no avail. Sorry man.